# JAX-RS packet size

Tags: json, web-services, jax-rs

I have a web service which sends out JSON objects using JAX-RS.  However, the transfer rate is very slow when it comes to transferring the JSON.  For testing, I've implemented the following code to simply return a map of value + number to numbers:

```
@GET
@Path( "test" )
@Produces( "application/json" )
public Response getTest(){
    Map<String,Object> theMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    for( int x = 0; x < 5; x++ ){
        theMap.put( "val" + x, x );
    }

    return Response.ok( theMap ).build();
}
```

The resulting object:

```
{
  "val0": 0,
  "val1": 1,
  "val2": 2,
  "val3": 3,
  "val4": 4,
  "val5": 5
}
```

When it transfers the values, Wireshark shows that the server send back each value in a separate TCP packet.  e.g. the first packet contains:

```
"val0":0
```

This is for all of the values in the JSON object, which means that for an object with 20 parameters, 20 different packets get sent.  This gets very slow to transfer all of the data, as the data that I have has probably 20,000 individual Javascript elements, which takes on the order of 20s to transfer.  I can transfer the same information through a normal servlet in <1s.

Is there a way to set the JAX-RS to not send the elements in the JSON object individually?  I have transferred all of the data in 1s by manually serializing the object and writing it out as as string using a `StreamingOutput`, but that feels like it is defeating the purpose of just returning the objects to serialize from the REST method implementation.

Comment: That's not the resulting object of this code. No `val5` would be produced by this code. What you describe is very hard to believe. The TCP Nagle algorithm alone would prevent it.

Comment: @EJP Whoops, you're right, it should only go up to `val4`.  Copy&paste error.  Interestinly enough, it works fine if I set the `@Produces` to be `text/plain` instead of `application/json`, so some part of the JAX-RS implementation is breaking it up.